# counting occurrences of word in binary search tree

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm working on creating a function word_count that counts the number of occurrences of the given word in a binary search. I'm having some trouble with how the logic would work, I'm stuck on the initial part. There's another function I created word_observe, that checks if a word is in the tree if it is not it adds it in and sets the count to one. If it is it increments count every time it comes across it. That could possibly be useful to understand the full program.

```
typedef struct tnode {
  char *word;
  int count;
  struct tnode *left;
  struct tnode *right;
} tnode;

tnode *word_observe(char *word, tnode *node) {

        if (node != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(node->word, word) == 0) {
                        node->count++;
                        return node;
                } else if (strcmp(node->word, word) < 0) {
                        node->left = word_observe(word, node->left);
                } else {
                        node->right = word_observe(word, node->right);
                }
        } else {
                tnode *newnode = (tnode*)malloc(sizeof(tnode));
                newnode->word = strdup(word);
                newnode->count = 1;
                newnode->left = NULL;
                newnode->right = NULL;
                node = newnode;
        }
  return node;
}


int word_count(char *word, tnode *node) {
        if (node != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(node->word, word) == 0) {
                        return node->count;
                } else if (strcmp(word, node->word) < 0) {
                        word_count(word, node->left);
                } else {
                        word_count(word, node->right);
                }
        }
        return -1;
}

int main(void) {
  tnode *counts = NULL;

  counts = word_observe("dog", counts);
  counts = word_observe("dog", counts);

  counts = word_observe("apple", counts);
  counts = word_observe("hello", counts);
  counts = word_observe("pineapple", counts);
  counts = word_observe("pineapple", counts);
  counts = word_observe("pineapple", counts);

  counts = word_observe("zebra", counts);
  counts = word_observe("zebra", counts);
  counts = word_observe("zebra", counts);
  counts = word_observe("zebra", counts);

  printf("apple: %d\n", word_count("apple", counts));
  printf("dog: %d\n", word_count("dog", counts));
  printf("pineapple: %d\n", word_count("pineapple", counts));
  printf("zebra: %d\n", word_count("zebra", counts));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*I'm stuck on the initial part*" is a bit vague. Can you describe a more specific problem that you are facing and/or ask a specific question? Also see: [ask].

Comment: @kaylum I think I understand how to traverse the tree, but I don't understand how I would increment the count value recursively

Comment: shouldn't `word_count` search for the word, taking the appropriate left or right branch, then read the count if it's found? I don't get why you're taking the right _and_ left path in the `else` block.

Comment: `return count + node->count;` is nonsense also, `count` is uninitialized, who knows that that sum will be. Simply `return node->count;` .. and at the end `return -1;` or something to indicate the word wasn't found. All code paths must return a value.

Comment: @yano I'm not sure if I understood you properly, but I just edited the code. Is that what you mean?

Comment: closer,, you still need to return the recursive calls so the `node->count` makes it all the way back to the original caller (`main`). See my answer. Also note that it's bad Stack Overflow practice to edit the code in your question in real time beyond simple typos and necessary additional information. It creates a "moving target" that can invalidate comments and answers, confusing future readers.

Comment: @yano Sorry about that I just recently started asking questions on here, thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

You're kind of close.  Your `word_count` function isn't searching correctly, which is puzzling since you *are* doing this correctly in `word_observe`.  You need to search down the left side for < words and down the right side for > words.  Since you're using recursion, you need to return those calls directly.  When the word is found, simply `return node->count`, what you're doing invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since `count` isn't initialized.  Finally, you must return a value to indicate if the word isn't found.

```c
int word_count(char *word, tnode *node) {
        if (node != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(node->word, word) == 0) {
                        // found the word, return its count. This value will
                        // ride the `return`s up the stack until it's returned back to main
                        return node->count;
                } else if (strcmp(node->word, word) < 0) {
                        // < word, take the left path
                        return word_count(word, node->left);
                } else {
                        // > word, take the right path
                        return word_count(word, node->right);
                }
        }
        // couldn't find the word, return -1
        return -1;
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cGMh5ancf)